# How to add/replace psobject

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script about the state of the server hardware

The following functions have been completed.

Get-SummaryStatus.ps1

Get-Memory.ps1

Get-PowerSupply.ps1

Get-Proecssor.ps1

Get-Fanstatus.ps1

```
Get-SummaryStatus.ps1 output is
Server         ServerStatus                  
------         ------------                  
AAA            {System.Collections.Hashtable}

$report.server output is 
AAA

$report.serverstatus output is 
Name                           Value                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                            
MemoryStatus                   OK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PowerStatus                    OK                                                                                                               
ProcessorStatus                OK                                                                                                               
Fanstatus                      OK
```

Get-Memory.ps1 output is

Server         MemoryStatus
------         ------------
AAA           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}

$report.server output is

AAA

$report.MemoryStatus output is

Name                           Value
----                           -----
MemoryID                       1
MemoryStatus                   OK
MemoryID                       2
MemoryStatus                   OK

```
Get-PowerSupply.ps1 output is

Server         MemoryStatus                                                
------         ------------                                                
AAA           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}

$report.server output is 

AAA


$report.PowerStatus output is 

Name                           Value                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                            
PowerID                       1                                                                                                               
PowerStatus                   OK                                                                                                               
PowerID                       2                                                                                                               
PowerStatus                   OK
```

Get-Proecssor.ps1 output Similar to the three above

Get-Fanstatus.ps1 output Similar to the three above

Duo to I have more than 1000 services that need to be monitored, So I want to make the following steps to improve efficiency.

I created a new main function（ServerHealthCheck） and call all sub-founcitons(summary,memory,power...) to main function. (completed)

If the summary state are OK, and then output summarystatus. (completed.)

If Summary memory status is failed. and then will call Get-Memory.ps1 to find which memory is bad.(completed)

If Summary power status is failed. and then will call Get-powersupply.ps1 to find which powersupply is bad.(completed.)

if One of the hardware was failed , I want to rearrange a new object.

my question is How to add/replace object to get expected output? thanks in advance.

```
Expected output(if summary memory status is failed):

Server         ServerStatus                  
------         ------------                  
AAA            {System.Collections.Hashtable}

$report.server output is 
AAA

$report.serverstatus output is

Name                           Value                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                            
MemoryID                       1   
MemoryStatus                   failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
PowerStatus                    OK                                                                                                               
ProcessorStatus                OK                                                                                                               
Fanstatus                      OK
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777). It's hard to understand what you're asking with the current formatting.

Comment: Is this a request for a code review? Your post does not contain a single questionmark

Comment: Based on what I am seeing here, you can get virtually all this (that you can then parse) via the built-in cmdlet.  --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo?view=powershell-7. What you are showing is separate scripts, not functions, yet, all of what you have here can be a single scrip tor function, using a hash table or PSCustomObject for singular reporting use cases. There are many of these scripts all over the web that already exist, that you can leverage and tweak as needed.